# Share data with all views in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to share a collection of notifications to all views under the `auth` middleware. I thought I might be able to just call `Auth::check()` but it seems to always return false?

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view)
        {
            $view->with('userNotifications', Auth::user()->notifications);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Research the request lifecycle.  Service providers are booted before the authentication session is established.

Comment: So how do I share it with all views but only when logged in?